# Playing sound from Database using MediaPlayer C#

Tags: c#, audio, media-player

I have sound stored in database in `byte[]` type. I can easily play with `SoundPlayer`, but not with `MediaPlayer`. Nice thing about `MediaPlayer` is I can play from middle of the sound. `SoundPlayer` doesn't have this feature. Is there way to play sound which stored in database with `MediaPlayer`(not from the filesystem). 
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the `MediaPlayer` class can only [`Open`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer.open.aspx) media from the file system - it's simply a limitation. It's only option is to receive a `Uri`. However, I would recommend leveraging [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com). With NAudio you can in fact play, pause, stop, rewind, and more all in memory.